# ngnix redirect every subdomain except www to a specific path

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I have the issue that i want to rewrite all subdomains except www to a specific folder.
The Problem is this is running inside a docker container with a external volume an dynamic hostname for different hosts. So i have to use $hostname. 
As soon as you use $hostname it gots the same threatment as a regex rule. So creating one rule for www don't work becuase it got the same threatment for www.$hostname as for *.$hostname or an regex there.

i tried multiple things, extracting it directly in a variable from the server_name that did not work at all and i'm now at a condition regex with a negative lookahead that works fine on any regex tester but not in the ngnix
2016/02/16 12:28:14 [emerg] 1#0: invalid condition "(?!www.)(\w" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:10

Anyone got any ideas?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80;
    server_name *.$hostname;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/rewrite.log debug;
    root /src/webapp/dist;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;

    if ($http_host ~ ((?:\w+(?:-\w+)*\.)*)((?!www\.)\w+(?:-\w+)*)(\.$hostname)) {
        set $subdomain $1;
        return 301 $scheme://www.$hostname/#/$subdomain/media/portfolio/1;
        break;
    }

}
```

Also tested below block, same result no redirect working at all, again it's located inside a docker container with a ngninx  1.4.6-1ubuntu3.4 :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.$hostname;
    root /src/webapp/dist;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.$hostname;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;

   return 301 $scheme://www.$hostname/#/media/portfolio/1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle it with two server blocks. The first server block will handle the `www.$hostname` and the second will work for all other cases.

Here is an example:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.$hostname;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;
        # Do whatever you want here
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name *.$hostname;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;
        # Do whatever you want here
}
```

If you had been thinking about some conditional `if` statements - Forget it. It's a bad idea. Nginx has support for `if`s but they are only there for very extreme cases and their use is highly discouraged as they don't work as in normal programming languages.

Comment: due some strange behaviour of nginx this nis what i stated that i already tried. it's not working because it is hjust ignored

Comment: @Mario Please update your question with your exact code I did tested the code I posted and it does work.

Comment: pasted above, still not working, no other configuration used, but i found out that you cannot use the variables in regex

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80;
    server_name *.$hostname;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/rewrite.log debug;
    root /src/webapp/dist;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;

    if ($host ~* "((?:\w+(?:-\w+)*\.)*)((?!www\.)\w{3,}(?:-\w+)*)(\..*\.muc\.pom)") {
        set $subdomain $2;
        return 301 $scheme://www.$hostname/#/$subdomain/media/portfolio/1/about;
        break;
    }

}
```

Ngninx somehow is not be able to use a variable in the regex, so i have to get around a little bit with dns endings, for production use there should also better solution, but hte regex is matching and rewriting.

I know If's are bad, if anyone can come up with another solution for docker please feel free to share